# React prop value not accessible within return statement of render() method while using ES6 class declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I am a React beginner and am facing an issue while trying to code up [Peter Beshai's Linked Highlighting](https://medium.com/@pbesh/linked-highlighting-with-react-d3-js-and-reflux-16e9c0b2210b) with React myself.

If i declare the propTypes like this:

```
export default class RadialHeatmap extends React.Component {

  _handleHover(d) {
    ChartAction.highlight(d);
  }


  render() {
    const { data, width, height, radiusKey, colorKey, highlight } = this.props;
    debugger; //debugger A

    // set up scales for radius and colour based on the min/max in the data set
    const strokeWidth = Math.ceil(width / (data.length * 2));
    const r = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d[radiusKey])).range([strokeWidth, (width - strokeWidth) / 2]);
    const color = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d[colorKey])).range(["#edf8b1", "#2c7fb8"]);


    return (
      <div>
        <svg ref="svg" width={width} height={height} className="chart radial-heatmap">
          {data.map((d, i) => {
            debugger; //debugger B
            return (
              <circle className={ classname } key={i} r={r(d[radiusKey])} cx={width / 2} cy={-r(0) / 2} 
                      strokeWidth={strokeWidth} stroke={color(d[colorKey])} 
                      onMouseEnter={ this._handleHover.bind(this, d) }
                      onMouseLeave={ this._handleHover.bind(this, null) }/>
            ); 
          })}
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

RadialHeatmap.propTypes= {
  colorKey: React.PropTypes.string, // the key for the colour value
  data: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  height: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  radiusKey: React.PropTypes.string, // the key for the radius value
  width: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  highlight: React.PropTypes.object,
};

RadialHeatmap.defaultProps= {
  radiusKey: "r",
  colorKey: "color"
};


export default RadialHeatmap;
```

Then my "highlight" and "data" props are accessible at debugger A but not at debugger B (see comment in code for reference).

But if I declare it using React.createClass then the code works and the variables are accessible at both debuggers:

```
const RadialHeatmap = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    colorKey: React.PropTypes.string, // the key for the colour value
    data: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    height: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    highlight: React.PropTypes.object,
    radiusKey: React.PropTypes.string, // the key for the radius value
    width: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
  },

  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      radiusKey: 'r',
      colorKey: 'color'
    };
  },

  _handleHover(d) {
    // send an action indicating which data point to highlight
    ChartActions.highlight(d);
  },

  render() {
    const { data, width, height, radiusKey, colorKey, highlight } = this.props;
    debugger; //debugger A


    // set up scales for radius and colour based on the min/max in the data set
    const strokeWidth = Math.ceil(width / (data.length * 2));
    const r = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d[radiusKey])).range([strokeWidth, (width - strokeWidth) / 2]);
    const color = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d[colorKey])).range(['#edf8b1', '#2c7fb8']);

    return (
      <div>
        <svg ref='svg' width={width} height={height} className='chart radial-heatmap'>
          {data.map((d, i) => {
            debugger; //debugger B
            // set the highlight class name if this element is highlighted
            const className = highlight && d[radiusKey] === highlight[radiusKey] ? 'highlight' : '';
            return (
              <circle key={i} className={className} r={r(d[radiusKey])} cx={width / 2}
                      cy={-r(0) / 2} strokeWidth={strokeWidth} stroke={color(d[colorKey])}
                      onMouseOver={this._handleHover.bind(this, d)}
                      onMouseOut={this._handleHover.bind(this, null)}
                    />
           );
          })}
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default RadialHeatmap;
```

I have been thinking about this for a day and can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I mucked about and it maybe because highlight is an object because if I pass another prop in the same manner, they are accessible. The same problem happens with the "data" prop. Makes it seems like arrays and objects are treated differently inside the return statement for some reason.

Comment: it is just debugger behaviour at least at latest chromium based browsers, seems it optimize the scope and narrows it to "used" vars in current scope, so debuger does not see them: https://jsfiddle.net/4qseLhm5/

Comment: try

`debugger;(data,highlight);`

Comment: Wow. That's awesome and irritating at the same time. Thanks a lot!